# Define integer (int); What's the default value?

Tags: c, int

```
int i;
int data[5] = {0};
data[0] = i;
```

What's the value in data[0]?

Also, what's the meaning of this line?

```
if (!data[0]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In most cases, there is no "default" value for an `int` object.

If you declare `int i;` as a (non-static) local variable inside of a function, it has an indeterminate value.  It is uninitialized and you can't use it until you write a valid value to it.

It's a good habit to get into to explicitly initialize any object when you declare it.

Comment: @James McNellis, You meant "`int` type", not `int` object, right? :)

Comment: @Jacob:  Types don't have values.  Objects have values.  An object that is not explicitly initialized might have some default value in some languages (or even in C, in certain circumstances).

Comment: @James McNellis Do you mind explaining then why this program outputs 5 zeroes? `int x[5];for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {printf("%d", x[i]);}`

Comment: @James McNellis I've never really heard the term "object" in the context of C variables. They're not strictly objects, are they?

Comment: @Jacob:  Because that's the result you happened to get when you compiled the program with your compiler with certain settings at a particular time.  When I compile and run that program, I get an output of `-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460`.  It's likely that your compiler is zero-initializing memory for you.  Mine, Visual C++ with standard debug build settings, is pre-initializing uninitialized objects with `0xcc` so that they are more easily detected.

Comment: @Jacob You got lucky, or your compiler implements a default value of zero.  But the ANSI C spec does not specify a default value for non-static data members.  And I've never seen a compiler spec define it that way either.

Comment: @Jacob:  An "object" in both C and C++ is just "a region of storage."  It's a sequence of bytes that represent something.

Comment: @James McNellis Thanks for the info, I've always used the term "object" when referring to instances of a class...

Comment: +1 for no default value, it could be a "random" number in the storage location - I got data[0] equals to 232111 one time an 51 on second try under linux

Comment: Note--a good habit in one language isn't a good habit in every language.  Java can help you quite a bit if you do not initialize variables to meaningless values (0, null...).

Answer (score 9):

It depends on where the code is written.  Consider:

```
int i;
int data[5] = {0};

void func1(void)
{
    data[0] = i;
}

void func2(void)
{
    int i;
    int data[5] = {0};
    data[0] = i;
    ...
}
```

The value assigned to `data[0]` in `func1()` is completely deterministic; it must be zero (assuming no other assignments have interfered with the values of the global variables `i` and `data`).

By contrast, the value set in `func2()` is completely indeterminate; you cannot reliably state what value will be assigned to `data[0]` because no value has been reliably assigned to `i` in the function.  It will likely be a value that was on the stack from some previous function call, but that depends on both the compiler and the program and is not even 'implementation defined'; it is pure undefined behaviour.

You also ask *"What is the meaning of this?"*

> ```
> if (!data[0]) { ... }
> ```

The '`!`' operator does a logical inversion of the value it is applied to: it maps zero to one, and maps any non-zero value to zero.  The overall condition evaluates to true if the expression evaluates to a non-zero value.  So, if `data[0]` is 0, `!data[0]` maps to 1 and the code in the block is executed; if `data[0]` is not 0, `!data[0]` maps to 0 and the code in the block is not executed.

It is a commonly used idiom because it is more succinct than the alternative:

```
if (data[0] == 0) { ... }
```

Comment: I really don't get why you say the value being assigned to data[0] in func1 is fully deterministic.. it seems 100% indeterminate as long as i has not been initialized

Comment: @Julius: In the context of `func1()`, `i` is a global variable and global (`int`) variables are initialized to 0 unless there is some other initializer specified.  (The story is slightly more complex for some other types, but all global variables are initialized, either to a specified value or to 'zero'.)  Now, if some other code has modified the value of `i`, then the value assigned to `data[0]` will not necessarily be 0, but the value is still defined and not indeterminate.

Answer (score 5):

if an integer is declared globally then it is initialized  automatically with zero
but if it is local then contains garbage value until and unless  itis given some value

Answer (score 4):

If an integer is not initialized, its value is undefined as per C

Answer (score 3):

Since you've included the `={0};`, the entire array is filled with zeros. If this is defined outside any function, it would be initialized with zeros even without the initializer. `if (!data[x])` is equivalent to `if (data[x] == 0)`.

Comment: `data[0]` is subsequently set to `i`.  The OP boils down to asking about what the value of `i` is, since it hasn't been assigned one.

Answer (score 1):

// File 'a.c'

```
   #include <stdio.h> 

   void main()
    {
            int i, j , k;
            printf("i = %i j = %i k = %i\n", i, j, k);
    }
```

// test results

```
> $ gcc a.c 
> $ ./a.out 
> i = 32767 j = 0 k = 0
```

Comment: Can someone explain this output?

Answer (score 0):

As @James McNellis stated in 2010, the standards for programming languages leave the initial value of a variable to the compiler implementation, and results differ from one compiler implementation to another.

I came here to review the state of affairs in this regard because I remembered observing that some compilers initialize arrays of integers to zero.

After reading the inconclusive answers recorded here, I constructed a small static method in the assembly that I use to conduct such experiments before I implement a technique in production code. My current project requires porting some JavaScript code to C#. Since the JavaScript interpreter doesn't initialize anything, that implementation opened with a FOR loop to initialize a large array of integers. Before I blindly left it in the C# implementation.

The method follows.

```
        private static void IntegerArrayGym ( )
    {
        int [ ] ints = new int [ 10 ];

        Console.WriteLine ( $"{TEST_INTEGER_ARRAY_GYM} Begin:{Environment.NewLine}" );

        int intArrayLength = ints.Length;

        Console.WriteLine ( $"    The test array consists of {ints} uninitialized integers.{Environment.NewLine}" );

        for ( int intJ = ArrayInfo.ARRAY_FIRST_ELEMENT;
                  intJ < intArrayLength;
                  intJ++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( $"    Value of integer at ordinal position {ArrayInfo.OrdinalFromIndex ( intJ )} = {ints [ intJ ]}" );
        }   // for ( int intJ = ArrayInfo.ARRAY_FIRST_ELEMENT; intJ < intArrayLength; intJ++ )

        Console.WriteLine ( $"{Environment.NewLine}{TEST_INTEGER_ARRAY_GYM} Done!" );
    }   // private static void IntegerArrayGym
```

The output follows.

CSharp_Lab, version 7.92.170.0
Begin @ 03/06/2023 22:58:49.124 (03/07/2023 04:58:49.124 UTC)

IntegerArrayGym Begin:

```
The test array consists of System.Int32[] uninitialized integers.

Value of integer at ordinal position 1 = 0
Value of integer at ordinal position 2 = 0
Value of integer at ordinal position 3 = 0
Value of integer at ordinal position 4 = 0
Value of integer at ordinal position 5 = 0
Value of integer at ordinal position 6 = 0
Value of integer at ordinal position 7 = 0
Value of integer at ordinal position 8 = 0
Value of integer at ordinal position 9 = 0
Value of integer at ordinal position 10 = 0
```

IntegerArrayGym Done!
Please press the ENTER (Return) key to exit the program.