# I have just started learning loops in c programming, and have attempted to create a simple program to test my knowledge but it will not work

Tags: loops

I simply want a program that has the user input a value for a and b, and will ask the user to repeat this process if the value a is less than b.
Here is my program:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
        int a, b ,c;

while (a<=b)
{
        printf("Please enter a value for a:\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("Please enter a value for b:\n");
        scanf("%d", &b);

        if (a<=b)
                printf("a must be greater than b:\n");
}
        c=a+b;
        printf("The answer of c is: %d\n", c);
return 0;
}
```

---

As soon as i run the program, it prints: "The answer of c is: 1829030"
(Please note that the last number is always random)

Please help me run this program.

Answer (score 0):

The value of an uninitialized non static local variable is indeterminate. This means that the value can be anything at run time. In this case, the values of a, b, c are random and the loop may or may not be entered based on the random values of a, b, c.

try -

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare variables `a, b, c` but you do not give them an initial value. That means that they have an indeterminate value.
Right after declaring `a and b` with no value given, you go on and compare them in your `while (a <= b)` condition. `C` does not know how to compare these value-less variables apparently, so it skips your loop altogether.
You could avoid this problem by giving `int a = 0, b = 1` values initially.
This way you make sure that the loop will at least run once.

What happens with uninitialized variables is explained in this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532871/define-integer-int-whats-the-default-value)

Comment: thank you!
However i have used programs without declaring a and b with values and the program worked. Could you please explain when you are supposed to declare these with values?

Comment: Please read this other answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532871/define-integer-int-whats-the-default-value