# Codeforces outputting something different

Tags: c

I have the following code.

CodeBlocks outputs `NO` for the following input, but Codeforces outputs `YES`?

For the following input:

`1500 1500 1500 1 2 3`, the right output is `NO` (correct in CodeBlocks), but it outputs `YES` with the Codeforces "compiler" (aka custom invocation).

I've tried everything and I'm very much out of ideas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int andrewGrapes, dmitryGrapes, michalGrapes;
int greenGrapes, purpleGrapes, blackGrapes;
int andrewCheck, dmitryCheck, michalCheck;

// how many grapes they want to eat
scanf("%d", &andrewGrapes); // green grapes only
scanf("%d", &dmitryGrapes); // purple and green
scanf("%d", &michalGrapes); // any grapes

// number of grapes
scanf("%d", &greenGrapes);
scanf("%d", &purpleGrapes);
scanf("%d", &blackGrapes);

if (greenGrapes >= andrewGrapes)
{
    andrewCheck = 1;
    greenGrapes = greenGrapes - andrewGrapes;
}

if (greenGrapes + purpleGrapes >= dmitryGrapes)
{
    greenGrapes = greenGrapes - dmitryGrapes;
    purpleGrapes = purpleGrapes - dmitryGrapes;

    dmitryCheck = 1;
}

//if (greenGrapes + purpleGrapes + blackGrapes >= michalGrapes)
  //  michalCheck = 1;

if (andrewCheck == 1)
{
    if (dmitryCheck == 1)
    printf("YES");
}   else printf("NO");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `andrewCheck` and `dmitryCheck` are never assigned a value for your given inputs. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4532871/6411653

Comment: `michalCheck` is never used at all and there is no need to `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: You should also validate the return of ***every*** user input function. (and initialize all your variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't initialize your variables so initially they contain random bogus values.
That's not a problem for `andrewGrapes`, `dmitryGrapes`, `michalGrapes`, `greenGrapes`, `purpleGrapes` and `blackGrapes` because they will each be assigned a value by `scanf` (assuming each call succeeds).

However, `andrewCheck` will only be assigned a value when `if (greenGrapes >= andrewGrapes)` is true. `dmitryCheck` will only be assigned a value if `if (greenGrapes + purpleGrapes >= dmitryGrapes)` is true.

If any or both conditions are not true the respective variable will retain it's random bogus value and when you proceed to test those variables the result will be as such.