# With the use of only 'Write' function how can i get to solve the following?

Tags: c

Create a function that displays ’N’ or ’P’ depending on the integer’s sign entered
as a parameter. If n is negative, display ’N’. If n is positive or null, display ’P’.

• Here’s how it should be prototyped :

> void ft_is_negative(int n);

This is what I did ;

```
int main()
{
void    ft_is_negative(int n);
int n;
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        write(1, "N", 1);
    }
    else
    {
        write(1, "P", 1);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

So this only prints P for me. I would like it to ask for the parameter and then print the result.

Comment: Where is your function definition? You only repeat the declaration and then have a bunch of code in your `main` function

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask]. In particular, it's very important to actually ask a question! You can normally identify a question by the presence of a question mark `?`. In your case, I can't tell what you're actually trying to ask! Please [edit] your question to include a... question.

Comment: *If n is positive or null* – `n` is not a pointer that it could be null.

Comment: @canton7: I guess "how can i get solve the following" in the title is meant to be the question... However, since the poster seems to lack the very basics of how to even *declare* a function in C, I'm not sure we can help them in a meaningful way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm *guessing* the problem is that the code doesn't compile, because it won't, but it would be nice if they actually said what the problem was

Comment: From reading your code, it looks like you're lacking some fundamental knowledge about C. I recommend starting with the course notes your teacher has given you so far, and asking them or your peers if you have questions. You need to know how to write a function before you'll be able to complete this task

Comment: @RohanBari I suspect they meant "positive or zero", and it didn't translate correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles (which is quite surprising, to be honest).

What you have right now is simply code that is executed inside the main function. `int n` is [an uninitialized variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532871/define-integer-int-whats-the-default-value) and you cannot know its value (apparently, it seems to be >=0 when you tried). In other words: the program currently has undefined behavior.

What you need to do: you need to declare and define a function which writes the required output. Once you have that, you need to call that function from your `main` function.

A function's signature follows the form: return type + function name + function parameters, e.g. `int fun(int num)`. A function needs a body too, which defines what this function does when called.

A very simple example:

```c
/* define the function "square", which takes a single parameter and returns the squared value */
int square(int num) {
  return num * num;
}

int main(void) {
  /* call the function: */
  int squared = square(5);
  /* squared now contains the value 25. you can use it in other calculations or function calls, such as `printf` */
  return 0;
}
```

With that, you should have the necessary information to rewrite your program to define a function, call the function and then write the function's output.

Answer (score 0):

1. > ... So this only prints P for me

   `n` is used uninitialized, that seems UB.
2. This line:

   ```
   void    ft_is_negative(int n);
   ```

   does nothing because of having no code contained in it, it's just a declaration.
3. Rest of the code does nothing whatever you're expecting from them.

---

**Solution:** Declare and define the function correctly and use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void ft_is_negative(int n) {
    // only write function
    if (write(1, (n >= 0) ? "P" : "N", 1) == -1) {
        // write failed
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n = 10;

    ft_is_negative(n); // P --- when -X -> N
    puts(""); // newline

    return 0;
}
```